# Defining a tuple as a parameter in scala classes

Tags: scala

I need to define val tuple in my scala case classe as value parameter

```
case class (v1:(a:String, b:String), v2:String)
```

but it gives me a compilation error..can someone point me how to that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't name the tuple elements in the class parameters, but you can in the class body.

```
scala> case class CC(v1:(String, String), v2:String) {
     | val (a,b) = v1
     | }
defined class CC

scala> val cc = CC(("X", "Y"), "Z")
cc: CC = CC((X,Y),Z)

scala> cc.a
res11: String = X

scala> cc.b
res12: String = Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the REPL, note the inferred type for a given value; for instance

```
scala> val t = ("a","b")
t: (String, String) = (a,b)
```

Hence

```
scala> val t2: (String,String) = ("a","b")
t2: (String, String) = (a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class v1(t: (String, String), v2: String)
```